# iOS 5.0 images does not in runtime after some time

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I've developed a game that uses UIImageView's to load images on the screen. At first it loads with no problem. But after some time, UIImageViews are being crated but they are transparent, so that there is no image loaded.

And this happens when I deploy my app with iPad with iOS 5. When i try it with iPad with iOS 4.x there is no problem.

Any idea??

Comment: what do you mean with "UIImageViews are being crated but they are transparent"

Comment: I mean, there is no image loaded in them.

Comment: make sure you load your image with [UIImage imageNamed:...]

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is a memory problem. 
make sure you load your UIImage with the method [imageNamed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed%3a)

```
[UIImage imageNamed:...]
```

not with initWithContentsOfFile. what does your used methods return? nil ?

Analyse your app with Instrument and watch the memory behaviour, especially when image loading fails